# Node.js will not install packages in project folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npx

I'm not sure what happened, but I've wasted six hours trying to fix Node.js as it just stopped working out of nowhere. Running **Windows 11** with **Powershell** & **Git Bash**.

When I try to run `npm install` in my local git repository with a Next.js application (*which I already initialized and even deleting and initializing again*), it does not work; rather, it installs my project as a package WTFF??

Whenever I run `create-next-app,` it also installs the dependencies to the global folder.

#### I've tried:

- Reinstalling Node.js (via Winget and Scoop)
- Removing `node_modules` folder globally
- Deleting package-lock.json
- Creating a new  project (*doesn't work on any repository*)
- Configure `--location` flag at default startup to `project`, but it still did not fix it.
- Deleting old package.json and initalizing a new one
- Creating a new project

### See below for screenshots.

- What it says every time I run `npm install` in any repository [image: What it says every time I run npm install in any repository]
- Result of `npm list` [image: Result of npm list]
- Modified Configuration file [image]

Please let me know if anyone has any idea, whether right or wrong. I tried looking online for related posts but couldn't find any like mine; if I overlooked any, please link them below. Thanks to anyone that helps, I have been losing my mind over this.

**EDIT:** When I set the flag for npm in the npm shim files, it does not work. But the workaround is to add `--location=project` every time I run an npm or npx command. I know you can set an alias to make life easier. How do I fix the configuration files?

I edited the shims located in: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix this problem; it had to do with a `.npmrc` already existing in my User folder, which automatically added it to the npm config, or I'm assuming. All I had to do with remove the `.npmrc` file in my home directory and run `npm config set location=project`, and it configured itself to install to the project directory by default.

#### Problem

`.npmrc` file existed when it should not have been there, so even though I reinstalled Node, the `.npmrc` never got deleted, so it always defaulted to the old configuration file and never worked.

#### Solution

- Run `npm config ls` to see your configuration file
- For me, there was a line in the configuration that looked like
  `; "global" config from C:\Users\Ashwi\.npmrc`
- I deleted the file, then updated the configuration by setting the default location to project 
  `npm config set location=project`
- Then I restarted Powershell, and everything worked perfectly. However, to install global packages, you must add the `--location=global` flag every time you run the command.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem landed me here. I had a further look into the npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/folders) and found something on there that helped me resolve the issue. It seems that if npm does not find a `node_modules`, or `package.json` it trawls your file system and uses a folder having any of these as your install directory.

Once I deleted some stray ones lurking further up it worked for me. Hope this helps.